# Laravel 4 testing "Command"s?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4

I've tried testing my commands in Laravel 4, as they are significant part of my system, but it seems like the documentation coverage is so poor, that they only explain basic testing of controllers and some models.

In Commands, you can pass arguments via command line to the class and it's received via $this->input property, something I don't know how to emulate.

Whenever I try to run the test for my command, when it expects an argument in "fire" method, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getArgument() on a non-object in /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php on line 153
```

Which is logical, there's no argument passed. Is there a way to test this functionality?...

Thanks

Comment: Why minus? this is a constructive question that can be backed with reference and real examples, and has no double opinion which can lead to conflicts, and it's a programming question. Showing what I have done is out of the context, because the question is super specific and can be answered easily. I think people forgot what the negative vote is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of it can be done using Symfony Command Tester (since Command is based on Symfony Console), example: http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Test-your-commands-in-Symfony2. However this would start to fail if you have to call another artisan command such as `$this->call('db:seed');` or etc because this is actually `Illuminate\Console\Application` specific syntax.

I'm all open if there anyone that have a solution for above scenario.

Answer (score -1):

I have recently made a post about [Testing Laravel commands](http://laravelista.com/testing-laravel-commands/).

If you have a specific part of code that you want to use in multiple commands then you have to move that part of the code somewhere where both commands can use it (Event handler, trait, another class ...) and then in your command reference that code instead of using `$this->call('db:seed');`